# Comparing means between two groups if dependent variable is a percentage

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, percentage

I have data on recovery rates from several hospitals across the country. The recovery rates are in percentages. 
I want to compare the mean recovery rate between two groups of hospitals, one that uses a certain procedure and one that doesn't. In other words, I want to test whether the difference between the mean recovery (in %) is significant.

I know I can't use usual independent samples t-tests because the dependent variable is a proportion and continuous. Not sure what test to use, would a Mann Whitney non parametric test be valid here?

many thanks

Comment: It may be better to describe your data in some more detail. How many percentages are there from one hospital or is there only one? Approximately, how many hospitals are being analyzed? Is there no absolute number available, for example, total patient attendance in the hospital or number of beds in the hospital? Because these will give some idea about the denominator for these proportions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The data only gives one proportion per hospital, there are about 24 hospitals. Un fortunately no Access to any denominator value like the number of patients/beds per hospital.

Comment: One can check the distribution or plot a boxplot with points to see which hospitals are within 25-75th percentile (inter-quartile range), which are outside and which are outliers: http://www.igorexchange.com/node/969

Comment: and how does that help me to identify the best test for differences of the mean values?

Comment: I think Mann-Whitney U will be a reasonable option. The most important assumptions are that both groups are independent and the responses are ordinal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test